# Интерполировать промежуточные значения между точками

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [8.7, 9.11, 8.55, 7.24]}, index=[22, 84, 140, 200])
df
```

[image: датафрейм]

Мне нужно сделать длину индекса от 22 до 200, заполнив промежуточные значения (между 22 и 84, 84 и 140, 140 и 200) прямыми, проведенными по точкам значений data.
Есть ли в Pandas или вообще в питоне готовая функция для этого?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста - индекс - это одна координата, а data - вторая? Есть линейная зависимость между индексом и data? Так? Или?..

Answer (score 0):

Нашел функцию `numpy.linspace()`
То, что мне нужно.

Comment: Ну да, это оно.

Comment: А можно увидеть конечный результат?